# References for Transition State Theory and Quantum Transtion State Theory

Tags: reference-request, books, transition-state-theory

Having asked recently [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/50988/estimating-stability-and-mean-life-of-anomalous-tautomers), I started to look for good references and notes on Transition State Theory and, also, modern versions of it including things like tunneling (which isn't taken into account in [Eyring's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eyring_equation)).

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find any satisfactory reference. I have downloaded a bunch of lecture notes and gained conceptual understanding of TST, but nowhere do I find a explanation with all the mathematical details.

What could you recommend for a thorough and detailed exposition of the TST?

Also, I would like to find stuff about how the theory has been improved over the years (the theory is mainly classical). I guess there are more accurate quantum mechanical versions of the theory.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am unaware, that there has been any development for an improvement of TST over the original publication by Eyring. The many flaws of his equation are being ignored to a certain extent and it still works. A short summary of the critical points can be found at Wikipedia or [in this question](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/10115/4945). I think starting with [the original publication](http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.1749604) is your only chance to understand it from a rigorous point of view.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン If my memory serves me correctly,  Eyring refered to the coordinate inaccurately  as a fourth translational freedom degree. I am unsure if would be simple to catch his idea without a very solid background. Glasstone's "A Treatise on Physical Chemistry" maybe is more friendly as an starting point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many sources that you can check out, in particular the reviews of Truhlar:

- [Current Status of Transition-State Theory](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jp953748q) by Truhlar et al.

This article was used in my undergraduate course of chemical kinetics, so I think that it could be a good source. Also we used:

- [Variational transition-state theory](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ar50156a002) by Truhlar and Garrett

Maybe they are a bit outdated, but they are good as start points. The abstract of this newer article make it seems to be useful for you

- [Transition state theory: Variational formulation, dynamical corrections, and error estimates](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jcp/123/18/10.1063/1.2102898) by Vanden-Eijnden and Tal

To deeply understand the theory statistical physics is a must. A good source (that also deals with TST) is the Ralph H. Fowler's book.

Comment: Thank you! That last reference is exactly the type of thing I was looking for.  It has the details and it clearly shows, for instance, how the ergodic hypothesis is crucial for TST, which is never clear in the chemistry literature, as far as I've seen. Also Atkin's "Physical chemistry" seems to be great for all of this stuff.

Comment: Your welcome. You should search for articles on Google Scholar, Scopus or similar sites.  ;-)